# My discord bot wont respond to the prefix I have set

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So basically I have been working on this bot for 2 days now for a friend's server so it can do the general things that he wants it to do. But I can't get it to respond to the prefix I have set for it.

Here is the code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = "$";

client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot is on!");
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if ($message.content.startWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === "test") {
        message.channel.send("test!");
    } else if (command == "youtube test") {
        message.channel.send("youtube test!");
    }
});
```

The token is at the bottom of the code but I didn't paste it here.

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to `message` as `$message` which won't work, and the proper function name is `startsWith()` not `startWith()`. Also, you probably want to make sure the message does NOT match the prefix, so you should use `!`.

Change it to:

```
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Dwosk answer, your problem is a typo mistake

> using `$message` instead of `message`.

What is very common and hard to note if you're not using a good interpreter/linter.

Also, seems like your logic is not doing what you want to.

> use `!` to check for messages that does not start with the prefix to break the function.
> `if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;`
> otherwise, you will be discarting all messages that start with your prefix ;)

Don't feel shame for it, those typo mistake are like trying to find grammar mistakes on your own text, you get blind.

This is why a good linter is recommended, I recommend you to try [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download), it's a free open source IDE that comes with a decent linter for js languages and you can always extend it with community extensions to give you a better experience